# Terence tao cauchy sequence example

Tags: real-analysis

In the example below, there is something I don't understand. He showed that we pick $1/k,1/j \leq \frac{1}{N}$. Why is it not $\frac{2}{N}$ ? I honestly don't why $|1/j - 1/k| \leq \frac{1}{N}$?
[image]

Comment: Because both are positive, so $|1/j-1/k|<\max\{1/j,1/k\}$. But you could continue the proof with the weaker $\frac 2N$ as well

Comment: Does this work for any n,m ? That is, let us say that $|n| \leq q$ and $|m| \leq q$ does it follow $|n - m| \leq q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arithmetically you can see it by adding inequalities:

$$0  <  \frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{1}{N} \text{ and } -\frac{1}{N}  \leq  - \frac{1}{j} < 0 \Rightarrow 0-\frac{1}{N} < \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{j} < \frac{1}{N}+0$$ $$ \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{N} \leq \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{j} \leq \frac{1}{N}$$
By interchanging $j$ and $k$ you get
$$-\frac{1}{N} \leq \frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{1}{N}$$

Both together give

$$\left|\frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{k} \right|\leq \frac{1}{N}$$

Comment: Does this work for any n,m ? That is, let us say that $|n| \leq q$ and $|m| \leq q$ does it follow $|n - m| \leq q$?

Comment: No. But it works for all $m,n$  with $\color{blue}{0} \leq m,n \leq q$. Otherwise you would get $2q$ as bound.

Comment: Maybe it helps to look at it as follows: 
If two numbers lie between $0$ and $q>0$ (including $0$ and $q$), then the distance between these two numbers can be at most $q$.

Comment: Yeah, that is perfect way of looking at it. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :-)